# Exoplayer video support crashing the app in release build

Tags: java, android, video, exoplayer

This crash occurs in playing the mp4 stream. Exoplayer version **12.2.0** . Android Run in debug mode - everything is fine. Run in release mode - app crashes

Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.Object com.google.a.a.c.a(java.lang.Object)"

```
  --------- beginning of crash
2021-02-10 12:52:49.385 4549-4645/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ExoPlayer:Playback
    Process: app.baff, PID: 4549
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.android.exoplr2avp.extractor.TrackOutput.sampleData(com.google.android.exoplr2avp.util.ParsableByteArray, int)"
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.readSample(Mp4Extractor.java:536)
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.read(Mp4Extractor.java:200)
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.read(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:127)
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1046)
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2021-02-10 12:52:49.385 4549-4649/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Loader:ProgressiveMediaPeriod
    Process: app.baff, PID: 4549
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.android.exoplr2avp.extractor.TrackOutput.sampleData(com.google.android.exoplr2avp.util.ParsableByteArray, int)"
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.readSample(Mp4Extractor.java:536)
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.extractor.mp4.Mp4Extractor.read(Mp4Extractor.java:200)
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.read(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:127)
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1046)
        at com.google.android.exoplr2avp.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in the proguard config file fixes the issue for me.

```
-keepnames class com.google.common.** { *; }
```

Visit
[google/guava#322](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3227) for more resources.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/RenderHeads/UnityPlugin-AVProVideo/issues/580

```
android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false

-keepnames class com.google.common.** { *; }
```